# Showing that tensoring with $id_A$ preserves injectivity of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, abelian-groups

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, $n \mapsto 3n$. Let $A$ be any abelian group, then the map
$$id_A \otimes f: A \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to A \otimes \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$$ is injective. It seems intuitive to me, because no matter what I choose for $A$ I cannot make $A \otimes\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ "smaller than" $A \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. However I know that tensoring does not preserve injective maps in general, so I am wondering how one can prove this statement?

Comment: Hint: $A\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong A/nA$.

Comment: Another proof : consider the map $g:\mathbb{Z/6Z\to Z/2Z}, n\to n$. Then $g\circ f=id_{\mathbb{Z/2Z}}$ so $(id_A\otimes g)\circ (id_A\otimes f)=id_{A\otimes \mathbb{Z/2Z}}$ and so $(id_A\otimes f)$ is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer not using the hints in the comments, but probably boils down to some of them.

Let $a\otimes b\in A\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Assume $0=(id\otimes f)(a\otimes b)=id(a)\otimes f(b)=a\otimes f(b)$.

Then we have that either $f(b)=nz$ with $z\in\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $na=0$ (in $A$), or $a=mx$ for $x\in A$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $mf(b)=0\mod 6$.

Note that $f(b)$ can only be $0$ or $3\mod 6$ and in the case $f(b)=0\mod 6$, also $b=0\mod 2$ and $a\otimes b=0$, so let as focus on $f(b)=3\mod 6$ ($b=1\mod 2$).

If $f(b)=nz$ with $z\in\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $na=0$. Then $n$ is odd. Thus we have $a\otimes b=a\otimes nb=na\otimes b=0$.

Finally, if $a=mx$ for $x\in A$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $mf(b)=0\mod 6$. then clearly $a\otimes b=0$, because $f(b)=3\mod 6$, so $m$ must be even, and in such case $a\otimes b=mx\otimes b=x\otimes mb=0$.